What is the correct translation of "my bloodline ends with me" in Latin?
I have tried to use google translator, but I know it can be grammatically inaccurate so I thought I’d ask here. Having trouble finding info elsewhere

Maybe "Mea linea sanguinis finit mecum."?

@FlatAssembler That's a very literal translation of the English words, but (as far as I can tell) linea sanguinis is just a calque of "bloodline" and wouldn't mean anything to a Roman. stirps (or perhaps proles) captures the sense better.

@brianpck The word "sanguis" may be used as "a descendant" Verg said "sanguis meus" so, "my blood(my descendants) "sanguis meus mecum finit." Sounds good.

@AntônioSilva But not with linea...
